# Proving $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} (x^4+y^4)/(x^2+y^2)=0$ by definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove by definition (and nothing else) that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} = 0.$$

I've been stuck on this for almost an hour with no luck, and ran out of ideas.
Can anyone help or give a hint?

Comment: maybe $(x^2+y^2)^2 = x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4$ can help.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach which is useful whenever you see a denominator of $x^2+y^2$ is to use polars: $x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$. Then
$$\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^4\cos^4t+r^4\sin^4t}
{r^2\cos^2t+r^2\sin^2t}=r^2(\sin^4t+\cos^4t)$$
which is clearly $\le 2r^2$. So as $r\to0$ the function tends to zero.
(Although as Luiz points out an even
stronger inequality is obvious.)

Comment: $\sin^4t+\cos^4t=1-2\sin^2t\cos^2t=1-\dfrac12\sin^2(2\theta)$ whose maximum value is $1$. So how is it $\le2r^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Take any $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose that $\|(x,y) - (0,0)\|<\delta(\epsilon) = \sqrt{\epsilon/2}$, which is to say that $x^2 + y^2 <\epsilon/2$.  We have
$$
\left|\frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2} - 0 \right| = 
\left|\frac{x^4}{x^2 + y^2} + \frac{y^4}{x^2 + y^2}\right| \leq
\left|\frac{x^4}{x^2 + y^2}\right| + \left|\frac{y^4}{x^2 + y^2}\right|\leq\\
\frac{(x^2 + y^2)^2}{x^2 + y^2} + \frac{(x^2 + y^2)^2}{x^2 + y^2} \leq\\
2(x^2 + y^2) < \epsilon
$$

Comment: Note that Luiz's trick (i.e. that of mathreadler's comment) lets us do the same with $\delta(\epsilon) = \sqrt{\epsilon}$.  That being said: when all you need is existence of the limit, it doesn't really matter how terrible your upper bound is for $\|f(x,y) - L\|$, as long as it goes to $0$.  A nice thing about my approach is that it works for most limits that you might see with an $x^2 + y^2$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\leq x^2+y^2$. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Obvious... if you're used to these kinds of proofs.

Answer (score 0):

These things are always nicer in polar form...

$$\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{r^4 (\sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta)} {r^2} =  r^2  (\sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta) \leq 2r^2$$

Let's assume $\|(x,y)\| < \delta$, that is $(x,y)$ is inside the open disk around $0$ with a radius of $\delta$.

Then using the above inequality we can guarantee that 
$$\left\| \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \right\| \leq 2\delta^2,$$
which in turn means that the image of $(x,y)$ is inside the open disk around $0$ with a radius of $2\delta^2$.

Therefore if you get an $0 < \epsilon$, and you pick $\delta$, such that $2\delta^2 < \epsilon$, then
$$\|(x,y)\| < \delta \Rightarrow \left\| \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \right\| \leq 2\delta^2 < \epsilon.$$